# AS i am using php version 8.0.3 . is these statements are defined in this version

Tags: php, session, cookies, runtime-error, version

How i fixed this issue need guidance.

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: setcookie(): Argument #3 ($expires_or_options) must be of type array|int, string given in D:\xampp\htdocs\ford\logoff.php:9 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\ford\logoff.php(9): setcookie('PHPSESSID', '1629284838', '/') #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\ford\logoff.php on line 9

```
<?php
  session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION["logged_in"])){

     $_SESSEION =[];

       if(ini_get('session.use_cookies')){

     setcookie(session_name(),time()-15,"/");
    }
      session_destroy();
       header("Location:login.php");

 }
 else{
    header("Location:login.php"); 
 }

?>
```

Comment: See https://www.php.net/function.setcookie -- You're missing the value as the second parameter, skipping straight on to the expiration, path becomes the 3rd argument instead of the 4th..

Answer (score 0):

From [session_destroy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy) man page:

```php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```